# Usar la función "si" dependiendo de una parte del texto de una celda

Tags: excel

Estoy intentando hacer una función que dependa SOLO de una parte del texto que impone la condición. En el ejemplo, quiero que si el texto de la columna A contiene la palabra VENTA (independientemente de lo que vaya detrás), le dé un valor de 1, y si no lo contiene, le dé un valor de 0 (que aparecería en la columna C):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intento es `=si(A1="venta*";1;0)`, pero no funciona. No sé si es problema del uso del asterisco o directamente no es la función adecuada.

Comment: Entiendo que estamos hablando de Excel ¿no?

Answer (score 1):

Si estamos hablando de una fórmula de Excel puedes utilizar:

```
=SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("VENTA";A1));1;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion, a diferencia de la otra respuesta, esta formula es **`CASE-SENSITIVE`** es decir , si hay una palabra como `VeNtA` devolvera `0`

```
=SI(ESNUMERO(ENCONTRAR("venta";A1));1;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo Una celda con el texto "DIPLOMADO jÓVENES TESOS POR EL AMBIENTE"
busco la condición extrayendo texto a la izquierda o derecha según necesidad de la condición y No de caracteres para la respuesta al ser verdadero le envió a traer valor de otra hoja o dejar vacío.

=SI(IZQUIERDA($C$29;9) ="DIPLOMADO";'HOJA DE COSTOS'!$C$8;0)

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta? o es otra pregunta relacionada con la principal.